# Is it possible to open Facebook share dialog (in Facebook app) from mobile web?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, iphone-web-app

We have similar functionality for Twitter -- linking to "twitter://post?message=Hello" will open the Twitter app (if installed). Is there a similar way to invoke in-facebook-app share dialog via "fb://"?

The reason we'd like to use "fb://" over "http://facebook.com?sharer.php?u=" is UX. From their phones, most FB and Twitter users use the native apps (not the mobile web versions) so their apps are logged in and their browsers are not. The "twitter://post" link works beautifully for Twitter, but we can't figure out if something similar is possible with Facebook (we tried most of what's on http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook but no dice. Even the actual share button invokes the fb web version, not the app). Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @NjaalGjerde as of now there is no solution for this provided by facebook.